# Listing Json data with Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

so i would like to list the first value of users json i get from making an rest api call with python so that the response is like this :

`0 :"XXX-XXX", 1 :"DDD-DDD", 2: "KKK-KKK", 3 :"UUU-UUU"`

Json Data from API call:

````
"XXX-XXX":{
   "Info":{
      "ID":"08",
      "Created": "2021-07-10",
      "Plan": "Basic"}},
"DDD-DDD":{
    "Info":{
       "ID":"04",
       "Created": "2021-07-11",
       "Plan": "Prime"}}
   },
"KKK-KKK":{
    "Info":{
       "ID":"02",
       "Created": "2021-07-11",
       "Plan": "Prime"}}
   },
"UUU-UUU":{
    "Info":{
       "ID":"13",
       "Created": "2021-07-11",
       "Plan": "Prime"}}
   }
 }```
````

Comment: Have you researched any potential solutions to your problem on the Internet?

Comment: @MontanaBurr Like i know how it works with js. it'd be Object.keys(users) but i can't figure it out using python and couldn't really find anything on the internet. maybe i'm not describing it right

Comment: You posted a decent question and said you'd tried to research the question so I gave you an upvote. However, you should be aware that StackOverflow more or less expects you to have shown an attempt to research a solution on your own. This can be done by researching related issues and posting in your question details about why the solutions you found don't work for you.

Comment: @MontanaBurr thank you, yes I'm aware of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so the solution is simple. Python includes a JSON module. So first you load the JSON as a Python dictionary using the load() method, then call the keys() method on the dictionary to get an iterable containing the keys. An iterable means you can iterate over it as if it were a list, but if you absolutely need a list, you can convert that object to a list.

Here's some code:

```
import json
json_string = """ { "X": {"name":"hi"},"Y": {name:"yo"}}
"""
dictionary = json.loads(json_string) # get a dictionary from the JSON
keys = dictionary.keys() # get the keys of the dictionary
for key in keys: #iterate over keys
    print(key)
key_list = list(keys) # converts keys to a Python list
```

Comment: thanks, working great.